# Extract data from session array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a session data using jcart and I want to extract some data into textbox

http://pastebin.com/0r54iSgj

How do I get the data :

```
[1] => Soccer Ball
[1] => 25.00
[1] => 2
```

Comment: They're `private`, so you can not get them through direct access. You will need public *getter* methods.

Comment: @CORRUPT How do I change the jcart code it to be taken?